# Moran's I test and LM tests for panel data in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, panel-data, spatio-temporal

I am trying to perform spatial panel data analysis using the `splm` package in R. However, I encountered an error when applying the Moran test and LM tests to the entire panel data.

I have generated random data over 10 time periods, including variables for income and crime. I created a spatial weights matrix using the `mat2listw` function.

Next, I converted the data into a panel data structure using the `pdata.frame` function and specified the individual and time indices. Then, I attempted to fit a spatial lag model with fixed effects using the `spml` function.

However, when I tried to apply the Moran test using the `moran.test` function to the residuals of the spatial lag model for the whole period, I received an error message: "objects of different length."

I received the same error when applying LM tests using the `lm.LMtests` function to the entire panel data. The `lm.LMtests` function is supposed to perform LM test for error dependence (LMerr), and LM test for a missing spatially lagged dependent variable (LMlag).

However, when I subset the data for a single period and perform the Moran test and LM tests using the same functions, the tests work correctly without any errors.

In my opinion, the error "objects of different length" occurs because the spatial weights matrix used in the tests do not have the same dimensions as the number of observations in the panel data.

Can anyone please help me understand why I'm encountering this error and how I can apply the Moran test and LM tests to the entire panel data successfully?

Thank you.

Code:

```
# Used library
library(splm)

# Here I generate random data
set.seed(123)
id <- rep(1:10, each = 10)
time <- rep(1:10, times = 10)
income <- rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 10)
crime <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
data <- data.frame(id, time, income, crime)

# creating a spatial weights matrix
mat <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 10*10, replace=TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- t(mat)[lower.tri(mat)]
diag(mat) <- 0
w <- mat2listw(mat, style="W")

# Converting the data into a panel data structure
pdata <- pdata.frame(data, index=c("id", "time"), row.names = FALSE)

# Creating spatial lag model with fixed effects
spml_model <- spml(crime ~ income, data = pdata, listw = w, lag = TRUE, 
                   model = "within", spatial.error = "none")

# Applying the Moran test - For the whole period
pdata$residuals <- residuals(spml_model)
moran_result <- moran.test(pdata$residuals, listw = w)
# Error - objects of different length

# Applying the Moran test - For one period
residuals2 <- pdata$residuals[pdata$time == 1]
moran_result <- moran.test(residuals2, listw = w)
print(moran_result)
# For one period it works

# Applying LM tests
lm_model <- lm(crime ~ income, data = pdata)
# For the whole period
res <- lm.LMtests(lm_model, w, test=c("LMerr", "LMlag", "RLMerr", "RLMlag"))
# Same Error - objects of different length

# Applying LM tests - now for only one period, however, now I use estimates of one period 
data3 <- subset(data, time == 1)
pdata3 <- pdata.frame(data3, index=c("id", "time"), row.names = FALSE)
lm_model <- lm(crime ~ income, data = pdata3)
res <- lm.LMtests(lm_model, w, test=c("LMerr", "LMlag", "RLMerr", "RLMlag"))
summary(res)
# Again, for one period it works
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `spdep` version of LM.tests, which are designed to work on pooled or cross-sectional data sets only. For spatial panel data you should use the `slmtest()` function from `splm` package to test for hypotheses for spatial lag or spatial error model selection. Currently, the command is programmed that you can only run on test at a time: "lml", "lme" (standard spatial lag and spatial error), "rlml", "rlme" (robust versions).

In your case you would do something like this

```
library(plm)
library(splm)
...
# Note I am using plm regression here, rather than just lm
plm_model <- plm(crime ~ income, data = pdata)

res1 <- slmtest(plm_model, w, test = "lml", model = "within", zero.policy = TRUE)
res2 <- slmtest(plm_model, w, test = "lme", model = "within", zero.policy = TRUE)
res3 <- slmtest(plm_model, w, test = "rlml", model = "within", zero.policy = TRUE)
res4 <- slmtest(plm_model, w, test = "rlme", model = "within", zero.policy = TRUE)

# I assumed here you are interested in "within" model and that your weights
# matrix could contain units with no neighbors, hence the last two arguments

summary(res1)
summary(res2)
summary(res3)
summary(res4)
```

On the basis of the results (p-values) you can select the more appropriate model for your spatial panel. The interpretation is the same as in the `spdep` version.

As for the Moran tests, the easiest would be to run them separately for each time period in your panel data (assuming you are interested in spatial lag only but not also the temporal lag). I am not aware of a Moran test function for panel data that would have the same setup as the `spdep` form. Though complicated, I suppose you could do this by running a regression for one time period, but using time-lagged independent variables from another time period. Then, running the `moran.test` on model residuals would give you the value for spatial AND temporal autocorrelation.